# Why is XBMC failing to play audio from my HDMI port?

Tags: server, sound, alsa, hdmi, xbmc

## I have the following setup:

- Ubuntu 14.04 Server
- Latest Nvidia video drivers
- ALSA installed
- PulseAudio **NOT** installed
- XBMC 13.1 Gotham installed

## The problem:

running `speaker-test -c2 -D plughw:1,7` produces sound via HDMI out, as expected, and the XBMC log suggests that the card is detected, but I'm still not getting any sound in XBMC.

## Relevant Information

- The output of `id` is `uid=1000(louist) gid=1000(louist) groups=1000(louist),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),100(users),110(lpadmin),111(sambashare)`, so I *am* in the `audio` group.
- I checked `alsamixer` and S/PDIFs are all unmuted on both audio devices.
- The device selected in xbmc is called `Default (HDA NVidia HDMI 0)`.

### aplay -l

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: VT1708BCE Analog [VT1708BCE Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: VT1708BCE Digital [VT1708BCE Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: VT1708BCE Alt Analog [VT1708BCE Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

### aplay -L

```
$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Alt Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Alt Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Alt Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, VT1708BCE Alt Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

### xbmc.log

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7816772/

### dmesg

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7816780/

#### Does anybody know how I can go about remedying this problem?

Comment: `NOTICE: m_displayName : Default (HDA NVidia HDMI 0)` isn't that your HDMI device?

Comment: @CL., Seems so, meaning that something has changed recently (it wasn't there before...).  Still, I'm not getting any audio output, so any help would be appreciated.  I'll edit the question.